# Why do I need to specify passenger_enabled twice?

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

I'm trying to set up my nginx.conf to use the asset pipeline in Rails 3.1. I'm using nginx 1.0.10 and Passenger 3.0.11. My nginx.conf looks like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name .example.com

  root /srv/project/public;
  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_use_global_queue on;

  # Assets shouldn't expire
  location ~ ^/assets/ {
    gzip_static  on;
    expires      10y;
    add_header   Cache-Control public;
    add_header   Last-Modified "";
    add_header   ETag "";
  }
}
```

However, when I try to access an asset, I get a 404 error (unless it's accessing the cache, of course). I figured out that adding `passenger_enabled on;` into the `location ~ ^/assets/` block will fix this problem, but I don't understand why this is needed when it's already specified earlier in the `server` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the passenger devs, [it's an nginx issue](http://groups.google.com/group/phusion-passenger/browse_thread/thread/52fb0c28ad61cc45#msg_9a00de13906b615a), and `passenger_enabled on` needs to be specified in every `location` block.